# Error trying to open windows mobile project

Tags: windows-mobile

I am trying to open a windows smart device project in vs2008 and I am getting the following error 'The application for the project is not installed'. I assume this is due to not having a correct version installed of a sdk. So far I installed:

- Pocket PC 2003
- Windows CE
- Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK
- Windows Mobile 5.0 SmartPhone SDK
- Windows Mobile 6 Proffesional SDK
- Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK

I have the follow .Net Compact Framework Version installed. 2.0 and 3.5

This is the contents of the .proj file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://...msbuild/2003"  ToolsVersion="3.5">
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<StartupObject>Sub Main</StartupObject>
<RootNamespace>abc</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>abc</AssemblyName>
<PlatformFamilyName>PocketPC</PlatformFamilyName>
<PlatformID>4118C335-430C-497f-BE48-11C3316B135E</PlatformID>
<OSVersion>5.1</OSVersion>
<MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>
<DeployDirSuffix>abc</DeployDirSuffix>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<OptionExplicit>On</OptionExplicit>
<OptionCompare>Binary</OptionCompare>
<OptionStrict>Off</OptionStrict>
<OptionInfer>On</OptionInfer>
<NativePlatformName>Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK</NativePlatformName>
<FormFactorID>
</FormFactorID>
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Thanks for your help.